# How to find root cause of effect with multiple distractors

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, bayesian-network

I am writing an app to determine most likely cause of stomache-aches of users. Reducing the problem to its simplest form, for each user I have a multiple lists of ingredients that leads to his/her stomache-ache. For example, the first dish to cause a stomache-ache might have milk, eggs, peanuts. The second dish to cause a stomache-ache might have milk, eggs, lobster, and so on. How can I aggregate these lists of dish ingredients to determine the ingredient(s) most likely to be causing the stomach-ache? Alternatively, is there a way to generate a score/probability of each ingredient causing the stomach-ache? It seems like a simple Bayesian problem, or perhaps a machine learning/clustering problem, but I haven't quite been able to root down the specifics.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. Since you've posted basically the same question on Math SE at [How to find root cause of effect with multiple distractors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304349/how-to-find-root-cause-of-effect-with-multiple-distractors), in the future, please provide a link here as a courtesy to help avoid duplication of efforts. Thanks.